# Windows 2008 Permission Issue: One User Can Open PDF Document And Another Cannot

Tags: windows, 64-bit, user-permissions, adobe

I don't really know if this is the correct place to ask this.

We have a Citrix Application that is hosted by a Customer at their company.
A portion of the Application opens a PDF Document so that other PDF Documents can be attached to it.  When one user runs this portion of the code, the PDF Files are attached to the main PDF Document.  However, he is the only user that can do this.  When other users log into the Citrix Application, the Code won't even open the Main PDF Document.

The Customer used to have Windows Server 2003.  This portion of the application worked fine for all of the users.

Adobe Acrobat 6.0 is used to merge and view documents in our application.  This part of the application works fine on other Windows 2008 servers.

Here is a portion of the Customers environment.

Windows 2008 R2 64 Bit 
Citrix XenApp 6.5
Adobe Acrobat 6.0 Pro
The Users use Roaming Profiles.

We will not be able to update the version of Adobe used by the Product any time soon.

The Server Guy at the company has done everything he can to make it so that other users can run this portion of the application.  He has given them temp admin rights and everything.  Nothing has worked out.

The Application tries and opens PDF Documents using CAcroPDDoc.Open(FileName).  Unfortunately, it does not return a useful error message.  The Event Log does not appear to be of much help.

Does anyone know any permission setting or profile setting that could be changed to resolve this issue on the Customer's Windows 2008 Server?

If this is the wrong place to ask this, would someone please indicate a better place?  I myself am not really a network guy.  I know a few basics and that is all.

Comment: Hmmm....this would sound to me like some type of file locking is involved if the permissions issue is ok.

Comment: Can you think of a reason why the file might be locked for one user and not another?

Comment: It appears to be corrupt permissions on an old server.  The Application can open documents on the new server.  This issue can be closed.